# How to establish associations for a model with two belongs_to relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I am building an application with the following model functions

- Groups have many Users
- Groups have many Expenses (each expense has a :name, :total, :added_by_user_id fields)
- Expenses have many owings (1 for each user in the group)
- Owings have an :amount and a :user_id, to reference which user the owing is referring

So far, I have set up the models as followings:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password
  has_many :memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  has_many :owings
end

# group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships
  has_many :expenses
end

# expense.rb
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :total_dollars, :name, :owings_attributes, :added_by_user_id      
  belongs_to :group, :inverse_of  => :expense
  has_many :owings, :dependent => :destroy
end

# owing.rb
class Owing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount_dollars, :user_id

  belongs_to :expense, :inverse_of => :owings
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :owings
end

# NB - have left off memberships class (and some attributes) for simplicity
```

To create an expense, I'm using @group.expenses.build(params[:expenses]), where params come from a nested model form that includes attributes for the owings that need to be created. The params include the 'user_id' for each of the 'owing' instances for that expense.

I have two concerns:

- Firstly - I've made 'user_id' accessible in the owings model, meaning that a malicious user can change who owes what in an expense (I think?).  I don't know how to get around this, though, because the user needs to see the names of all the other members of the group when they fill out the expense/owings form.
- Secondly - I've also made 'added_by_user_id' accessible in the expense model - I also wouldn't want malicious users to be able to change this, since this user_id has special edit/delete priveleges for the expense.  Is there some clever way to make an expense 'belong_to' a User AND a group, and set both of these associations when creating WITHOUT having to make either an accessible attribute?  If it helps, the 'added_by_user_id' can always be set to the current_user.

Any ideas?  Very possible I'm missing something fairly fundamental here.

Thanks in advance!

PS. Long time listener, first time caller.  Thanks to all of you for teaching me ruby on rails to date; this website is an incredible resource!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about setting them dynamically?

[dynamic attr-accessible railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - interesting railscast, I wasn't familiar with dynamic attr-accessible.  I don't think this is going to help me, though - I can use a before_filter in my controller to stop unauthorised users form editting/deleting expenses.  But I still need to keep :added_by_user_id (in Expense) and :user_id (in Owing) accessible given they are initially assigned from params.  I suppose there is no way to get around this, given there is no way to remove them from params.  Is the best bet just to have really thorough validation to prevent something iffy from happening?

Comment: I think I've come to a landing on this.  For the first issue, user_id HAS to be accessible.  A user needs to be able to say how much each user owes.  I'll just make sure a user passes an authorisation test before being allowed to update/edit, and that whatever an authorised user sets is legal.  For the second issue, i've set up an attributing setting method in the model (def set_user(user) ) - this means I can remove it from 'attr_accessor' so it can't be set by mass assignment.  Thanks for your answer though;  you taught be something so I'll accept your answer.  Cheers.